# Calendar Logic with Laravel and php-Carbon - Date parser

Tags: php, laravel, date

I am trying to create a date parser for a company schedule. I want to copy the previous month current week, day to previous month same week day. In instances where the date is in the same month I want to copy the previous month to that same week and day. I keep running into issues because weeks structures are different month to month. Also, working with the 31st returns the wrong month. So I tried creating logic for that. However I keep finding new problems when converting the date. Hoping someone can help me get on the correct path.
Initially I tried creating an array of each month and using it as a table but ran into issues with that as well. Below is what I have mostly working but still has issues with several dates returning the wrong week. Hopefully this makes sense.

[image]

```
 public function parser($day = "2 feb 2023") {

    $date = Carbon::parse($day);
    $dayOfWeek = $date->copy()->dayOfWeek;
    $numberOfWeek = $date->copy()->weekNumberInMonth;
    $newDate = $date->copy()->subMonth()->startOfWeek(Carbon::SUNDAY)->next($dayOfWeek);
    $lastOfMonthNewDate = $date->copy()->subDay(1)->subMonth(1)->startOfWeek()->next($dayOfWeek);


    if (($date->day == 31) && ($lastOfMonthNewDate == $date->isSameMonth($lastOfMonthNewDate))) {

        return $lastOfMonthNewDate->copy()->subMonth(1)->startOfWeek()->next($dayOfWeek);

    } else if ($date->day == 31) {

        return $lastOfMonthNewDate;

    } else  if ($newDate == $date->isSameMonth($newDate)) {

        return $newDate->copy()->subMonth(1)->startOfWeek()->next($dayOfWeek);

    } else {
            
            return $newDate;
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Still struggling with the logic on this. Not sure what the relation is. Tried the below code but, Jan,Oct,Nov all return the wrong dates. Also, Mar,April,Jun,Jul,Sep,Dec return wrong dates for 29,30,31. I am sure I am over thinking it now but no go.

```
    public function parser2($day){
    $date = Carbon::parse($day);
    $dayOfWeek = $date->copy()->dayOfWeek;
    $date4Week = $date->copy()->subWeek(4);
    $date5Week = $date->copy()->subWeek(5);
    $currentWeek = $date->copy()->weekNumberInMonth;
    $prevWeek = $date->copy()->subWeek(4)->weekNumberInMonth;


    if ($date->isSameMonth($date4Week) == 1) {

        if ($currentWeek != $date5Week->copy()->weekNumberInMonth) {
           return $date->subMonth();
        }else{
            return $date4Week->copy()->subWeek();
        }
    }else {

        if ($prevWeek != $currentWeek) {
            return $date5Week;
        }else{
            return $date4Week;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, don't you just need to subtract either 4 or 5 weeks? You just need to figure out which one, depending on the relation of the current date's weekday, to the weekday of the first of the month (I think) ...

Answer (score 1):

All you should need to do is subtract 4 weeks. If you're still in the same month, subtract one more. You can extend the Carbon class to do this by creating a [macro](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-macro) in a [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/providers) class.

Run `artisan make:provider CarbonMacroProvider` to generate a blank provider class.

Add the new provider class to the `providers` array in `config/app.php`.

```php
return [
    ...
    'providers' => [
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\CarbonMacroProvider::class
        ...
     ],
    ...
];
```

Edit `app/Providers/CarbonMacroProvider.php` to look like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CarbonMacroProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Carbon::macro("previousMonth", static function (): Carbon {
            /** @var Carbon $date **/
            $date = self::this();
            $last = $date->copy()->subWeeks(4);

            return $last->month === $date->month ? $last->subWeek() : $last;
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your app you can do this:

```php
echo Carbon::parse("20 july")->previousMonth()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo Carbon::parse("31 october")->previousMonth()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo Carbon::parse("2 november")->previousMonth()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Output:

```
2023-06-22 00:00:00
2023-09-26 00:00:00
2023-10-05 00:00:00
```

Comment: Appreciate your time. This is close to what I had and works for most dates. I do like the service provider approach. For example when I choose 10/1 , I want 8/27. It depends on how the first week is. And in a case like July 31 where the result would be July 3rd I would like to subMonth again to produce May 29. I am using a six week calendar and just crossing the days over. Hopefully it make sense. My head hurts trying to figure out the different rules.

Comment: Here is a list of a few dates and their expected result:  10/1 => 8/27, 07/31 => 06/29, 12/31 => 10/29, 03/29 => 02/01

Comment: Well what you’ve just described there is completely different from your question. Nobody can help you if you don’t have an algorithm to work with.